# npm start not opening browser after creating react js app

Tags: reactjs, npm-start

[image]

Please help me to get through the errors and where to debug them

Comment: Could you please provide a link to your code if possible?

Answer (score 0):

would you mind checking if all packages required for the tutorial installed?
if it fails to check on the package.json file and look at the scripts it should have the targeted files required to run the script and start with the node by node .js file and see what happens
also, share the git repo so I can get the insights on how to help

Answer (score 0):

Your application misses the start command from package.json

Go to **package.json** in your project and check this:

[image]

If you don't have it, please add it.